# Hide duplicated list items/list items with same content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a [codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/xgBeaJ) where you have to select some tabs, then you can insert your name and press submit and your name gets appended to the selected tabs. The thing is when you select multiple tabs (i did that with the jQuery selectable widget) and add your name to them, your name gets displayed multiple times. Thats pretty obvious because it gets added to every tab and that should be like that.
My goal is that javascript just hides the "duplicated" list items. So your name is just there once, but still on each tab you selected.
Thats my js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#plannername').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#plannername').attr("placeholder", "zuerst Tage auswählen");
    $('#plannersubmit').attr("value", " ");
    function selectionChange(event, ui) {
        var items = $('.ui-selected', this).map(function () {
            return $(this).index();
        }).get();
        $("section").each(function () {
            $(this).toggle(items.indexOf($(this).index()) > -1);
        });
        $('#plannername').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#plannername').attr("placeholder", "Name eingeben");
        $('#plannersubmit').attr("value", "eintragen");
    }

    $("#selectable").selectable();
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: selectionChange,
        unselected: selectionChange
    });
});


$(function(){
    $('#plannerform').submit(function(e){
        var val = $(this).find('#plannername').val();
        $('ul.plannerlist:visible').append('<li>' + val + '</li>');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#plannername').val('');
    });
});
```

And these are my HTML tabs:

```
<div id="content">
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>  
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>  
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul> 
  </section>
</div>
```

If you need to see my whole code, you can check out my codepen, which I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like 2 events will make tabs show content - selecting a tab, then selecting a tab and submitting the form. On both of those events, I would loop through the visible tabs, and hide any duplicates.

Created a function called `clearDupes()` that will hide duplicates, and calling it in `selectionChange()` and on `$('#plannerform').submit()`

Here's a pen since the form won't submit on SO http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/YNoVOo

```js
$(function() {

    function clearDupes() {
        var arr = [];
        $('.plannerlist li').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.tabcontent:visible').each(function() {
            $(this).find('.plannerlist li').each(function() {
                var nameText = $(this).text();
                if (arr.indexOf(nameText) > -1) {
                    $(this).addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    arr.push(nameText);
                }
            })
        })
    }

    // define one function, to be used for both select/unselect
    $('#plannername').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#plannername').attr("placeholder", "zuerst Tage auswählen");
    $('#plannersubmit').attr("value", " ");

    function selectionChange(event, ui) {
        // Get indexes of selected items in an array
        var items = $('.ui-selected', this).map(function() {
            return $(this).index();
        }).get();
        // Show or hide sections according to the corresponding option's selection
        $("section").each(function() {
            $(this).toggle(items.indexOf($(this).index()) > -1);
        });
        $('#plannername').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#plannername').attr("placeholder", "Name eingeben");
        $('#plannersubmit').attr("value", "eintragen");
        clearDupes();
    }

    $("#selectable").selectable();
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: selectionChange,
        unselected: selectionChange
    });

    $('#plannerform').submit(function(e) {
        var val = $(this).find('#plannername').val();
        $('ul.plannerlist:visible').append('<li>' + val + '</li>');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#plannername').val('');
        clearDupes();
    });
});
```

```css
*{
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#selectable .ui-selecting { 
  background: #9eefbc;
  transition:.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;
 transition: transform 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-180deg);
 transform: perspective(300px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-180deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
 perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
}
#selectable .ui-selected { 
  background: #6dce91; 
  transition:all 0.8s;
}
#selectable { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  position:absolute;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left:20%;
  display:flex;
  transition:.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index:1;
  margin-top:3px;
}
#selectable li { 
  background:#ddffea;
  padding: 0.6em; 
  font-size: 1.4em; 
  flex-grow:1;
  transition:.3s ease-in-out;
  border:none;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:0.8em;
}

#selectable .ui-selected:after,
#selectable .ui-selected::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity:1;
    animation:dreieckFade 1s forwards;
    border-top: solid 15px #6dce91;
    border-left: solid 20px transparent;
    border-right: solid 20px transparent;
}

@keyframes dreieckFade{
    0%{opacity:0;border-top: solid 0px #6dce91;}
    100%{opacity:1;border-top: solid 15px #6dce91;}
}

.ui-selectable-helper {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#content{
  width:60%;
  background-color:#9eefbc;
  margin-left:20%;
  padding-top:70px;
  margin-top:3px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}

.tabcontent{
    top:44px;
    background-color:transparent;
    z-index:0;
    transition:.3s ease-in-out;
    font-size:2em;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
}

#plannername{
  width:40%;
  background-color:#9eefbc;
  margin-left:20%;
  border:0;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:20px;
}
#plannername:focus{
  outline:0;
}
#plannersubmit{
  width:20%;
  background-color:#6dce91;
  border:0;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:20px;
  transition:.2s ease-in-out;
}
#plannersubmit:hover{
  transition:.2s ease-in-out;
  padding-left:40px;
  cursor:pointer; 
}
#plannersubmit:focus{
  outline:0;
}
#plannersubmit:active{
  color:white;
}
.plannerlist{
    list-style-type:none;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<form id="plannerform">
    <input id="plannername" placeholder="Name eingeben" type="text" autocomplete="off"></input><!--
    --><input id="plannersubmit" type="submit" value="eintragen"></input>
</form>
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">FR PM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SA AM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SA PM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SO AM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SO PM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">MO AM</li>
</ol>
<div id="content">
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>  
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>  
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul> 
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. The thing with your code is that the input text only get appended to the first of the selected tabs. Example: when you select 1-3 and add something to it, it's only visible on tab 1. :/

Comment: @TobiasGlaus how should it be instead? I thought you only wanted the name to display once if it was entered on multiple tabs.

Comment: Example: You add "Hello" on tab 1-4. Then "Hello" is visible on each tab. But when you got 1-4 selected, it's not like "Hello" "Hello" "Hello" "Hello", because it is on every tab from 1 to 4. It only display once then. I hope you get what I mean

Comment: Wow, that's perfectly it! Thanks alot!

Comment: @TobiasGlaus awesome! np :)

Comment: To whoever downvoted me, I would love to know the reason so that I can learn from any mistakes I've made!

Comment: That's just a little disadvantage of the stack community. You solved my problem perfectly, so you deserve nothing than upvotes.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus thanks :) Yeah I'd just like to know why, and if I should have taken a different approach or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this function to your code:

```
function isUnique(name) {
    var is_unique = true;

    $('ul li').each(function(item, index) {

        if ($( this ).text() === name) {                  
            is_unique = false;
        }
    });  

    return is_unique;
}
```

We compare the text of every list item with the current name we're attempting to append to the visible list.

You could use the function like this:

```
var val = $(this).find('#plannername').val();       

if (isUnique(val)) {
    $('ul.plannerlist:visible').append('<li>' + val + '</li>');
    $('#plannername').val('');            
}

...
```

[Forked demo](http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/bgPWqd)

Comment: Thanks for answering but what exactly changes that ? When I add "Hello" to 1-3 and select these tabs, I still see "Hello" "Hello" "Hello". :/ I think I should reformulate my question, that you guys can understand my goal better.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus I've updated my example (and forked demo) to work across multiple lists.

Comment: @AndyHoffman apologies if this wasn't you, but did you downvote my answer? I got a random downvote, and if I'm doing something wrong, I'd love to know why so that I can do it better.